# Sounds Button - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to implement a button in SpriteKit to enable/disable sounds in a game. I have the logic of the toggling correct.

The problem I have is that when I change the texture of the button, the new texture gets distorted since the image for "sound off" is slightly
 different in size from the "sound on" image.

How can I have both images display correctly using the same button?

Thanks!

Comment: Good practice would be using images of the same size to prevent problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to working, thanks to r-masand for the hint.
This is how it worked for me:

```
soundButton.scale(to: SKTexture(imageNamed: soundTextureName).size())
```

I had to get the size from the actual texture.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the texture of the `SKNode` `buttonSprite`, use scale to resize the new texture to the size of the `SKNode`.

```
buttonSprite.scale(to: buttonSprite.frame.size)
```

This should scale the texture to the size of the `SKNode`, fitting the button you already have.